# Alguna idea de porque no me guarda datos en fireStore?

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, kotlin, login, firebase-storage

He hecho el siguiente código y no consigo que me muestre los datos introducidos en una base de datos de FireStore, en el mainActivity me conecto a firebase para logear y quiero que guarde los datos introducidos en usuarioActivity pero no funciona, sospecho que puede ser que la variable "editTextTextPersonName.toString()).set(" la estoy llamando de MainActivity, actividad donde se introduce el mail:

class usuarioActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var binding: ActivityUsuarioBinding
private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuario)
    intextt.setOnClickListener{showDatePickerDialog()}
    intextt2.setOnClickListener{showTimePickerDialog()}
    outtext.setOnClickListener{showTimePickerDialog2()}
    
    binding = ActivityUsuarioBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    //setContentView(binding.root)
    auth = Firebase.auth

    //signOut()
    guardar.setOnClickListener{

        db.collection("users").document(editTextTextPersonName.toString()).set(

            hashMapOf("date" to intextt.text.toString(),
                      "hourin" to intextt2.text.toString(),
                      "houtout" to outtext.text.toString()  )
        )
    }
}

private fun signOut(){

    Firebase.auth.signOut()
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)


}

private fun showTimePickerDialog() {
    val timePicker = TimePickerFragment {onTimeSelected(it)}

    timePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "time")

}

private fun showTimePickerDialog2() {

    val timePicker2 = TimePickerFragment { OnTimeSelected2(it) }

    timePicker2.show(supportFragmentManager, "time2")

}

private fun onTimeSelected(time: String) {


    intextt2.setText("Ha seleccionado: $time")
}

private fun OnTimeSelected2(time2: String) {


    outtext.setText("Ha seleccionado: $time2")

}

private fun showDatePickerDialog() {
    val datePicker = DatePickerFragment{day, month, year -> onDateSelected(day, month, year) }
    datePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "datePicker")

}

fun onDateSelected(day:Int, month:Int, year:Int){

    intextt.setText("Ha seleccionado: $day/$month/$year")

}
```

}

Como se puede observar la parte de llamar a crear una base de datos empieza aquí guardar.setOnClickListener{

El logcat me dice lo siguiente:

> *2021-12-05 08:56:03.538 9493-9493/com.jf.check_incontrol E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.jf.check_incontrol, PID: 9493
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.widget.EditText.toString()' on a null object
> reference
> at com.jf.check_incontrol.usuarioActivity.onCreate$lambda-3(usuarioActivity.kt:37)
> at com.jf.check_incontrol.usuarioActivity.lambda$xWqmts6P690oyY93EDLmOlS_vaI(Unknown
> Source:0)
> at com.jf.check_incontrol.-$$Lambda$usuarioActivity$xWqmts6P690oyY93EDLmOlS_vaI.onClick(Unknown
> Source:2)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
> at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at texto en itálicacom.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)*

En la 37 es donde empieza esta parte, creo que lo que introduce el mail que introduce el usuario en la MainActivity lo tendria que llamar de otra forma en vez de:

```
editTextTextPersonName.toString()).set

db.collection("users").document(editTextTextPersonName.toString()).set(

                hashMapOf("date" to intextt.text.toString(),
                          "hourin" to intextt2.text.toString(),
                          "houtout" to outtext.text.toString()  )
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Algun mensaje en el LogCat? es importante revisar.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, he actualizado la publicación con el código, parece que le estoy dando "editTextTextPersonName.toString()).set" y que creo que es null, pero no se como llamarlo, es el texto que se introduce en la mainActivity para logear y esta es la usuarioActivity

Comment: En tu archivo activity_usuario.xml debe estar ese EditText, que id tiene?

Comment: Es el editTextTextPersonName

Answer (score 0):

El problema se indica en el LogCat y dice que estas llamando de una instancia de `EditText` con valor null:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
> android.widget.EditText.toString()' on a null object reference

Dentro de `onCreate()` debes obtener la referencia de la vista, primeramente asegura que en tu layout `activity_usuario.xml` se tenga el EditText y en base a su id obtener la referencia :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_usuario)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    //Obtiene la referencia del EditText.
    val editTextTextPersonName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName) 

    //signOut()
    guardar.setOnClickListener{

        db.collection("users").document(editTextTextPersonName.toString()).set(

            hashMapOf("date" to intextt.text.toString(),
                      "hourin" to intextt2.text.toString(),
                      "houtout" to outtext.text.toString()  )
        )
    }
}
```

---

El `EditText` con id `editTextTextPersonName` debe existir en `activity_usuario.xml`, esto es importante, si no existe eso es el problema.

Comment: Hola Elena, gracias por la respuesta, lo he hecho tal y como me has dicho pero me sigue diciendo que es null, el id del editext del mainActivity que quiero traer a usuarioActivity es el editTextTextPersonName, deberia ser así:

val email = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)

db.collection("users").document(email).set(
                hashMapOf("date" to intextt.text.toString(),
                    "hourin" to intextt2.text.toString(),
                    "hourout" to outtext.text.toString()  )

Aunque me obliga a añadirle el toString, el tutorial que sigo no lo añade

Comment: Pero ese EditText con id editTextTextPersonName si existe en activity_usuario.xml? esto es importante, si no existe eso es el preoblema

Comment: ese EditText es el que pone el usuario en el mainActivity, cuando se logea ya está dentro de usuarioActivity, es decir editTextTextPersonName solo está en mainActivity y quiero utilizarlo en usuarioActivity

Comment: La causa del error "Alguna idea de porque no me guarda datos en fireStore?" es lo que comento, tratas de obtener la referencia de un EditText en una Activity pero este se encuentra en otra Activity.  Te sugiero realices otra pregunta sabiendo que lo que necesitas es leer el valor del editText desde otra Activity.